# Creating Index page Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on creating an Index page in my Excel workbook as it is composed of many worksheets.  The code below esentially should insert a new row starting from Cell A1 and create a hyper link that links each worksheet back to the Index, however I keep having an issue where everytime I click Back to Index another "Back to Index" Hyperlink is created, do I have some kind of loop going on in my code?  I'm somewhat new to VBA and no the greatest an deciphering issues just yet.  Thank you very much for any anticipated help!! :)

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim l As Long

    l = 1

    With Me
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
        .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
    End With

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
            l = l + 1
            With wSheet
                .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
                .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:="Back to Index"
            End With
            Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 1), Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
        End If
    Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you putting the index? On a separate workeheet called `index` or on an existing sheet?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421358/excel-index-table-of-contents-macro

Comment: The first worksheet is the Index and yes it is called "index", the error lyes somewhere with the Insert Row code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that this is in the "Worksheet_Activate()" event. Every time you activate this worksheet (I assume this is the `Index` worksheet) it runs this code which loops through each worksheet that isn't the `Index` worksheet and inserts a new row with a hyperlink.

Since you only need to run this once, then take it out of `Worksheet_Activate()` and give it it's own Subroutine. You can call it when needed, but not every single time you activate the `Index` tab.

Alternatively you could check to see if the Hyperlink has been made on each worksheet, and if it has, then skip that bit of the macro. Something like:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim l As Long

    l = 1

    With Me
        .Columns(1).ClearContents
        .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
        .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
    End With

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        'Added a check to see if the hyperlink has been created yet already for each sheet
        If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name AND NOT(wSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Back to Index") Then
            l = l + 1
            With wSheet
                .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
                .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
                .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A1"), Address:="", _
                SubAddress:="Index", TextToDisplay:="Back to Index"
            End With
            Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 1), Address:="", _
        SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
        End If
    Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Dim wSheet As Worksheet
Dim l As Long

l = 1

With Me
    .Columns(1).ClearContents
    .Cells(1, 1) = "INDEX"
    .Cells(1, 1).Name = "Index"
End With

For Each wSheet In Worksheets
    If wSheet.Name <> Me.Name Then
        l = l + 1
        With wSheet
            .Range("A1").Name = "Start_" & wSheet.Index
            .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
        End With
        Me.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Me.Cells(l, 1), Address:="", _
    SubAddress:="Start_" & wSheet.Index, TextToDisplay:=wSheet.Name
    End If
Next wSheet
End Sub
```