# Adding from next sheet to the end sheet

Tags: excel

Assume I have n sheets.  My second sheet is called "Calc", which is where I do my summation/calculation.

I'd like to add everything A1, A2... A1000, to Z1, Z2...Z1000 from sheet 3 (sheet after Calc) to sheet n.

These are imported sheets.  I do not know the name of these sheets and I am not allowed to change them.

Any of the sheets between and including sheet 3 to sheet n can be removed or added at any time.

First I was thinking of trying =SUM('*'!A20), but it automatically changes the '*' to the first and last sheet.

When I remove the last sheet, it gives me error and the calculation fails.  I was thinking of doing indirect, but it would be very tedious, as I cannot drag to change the cells in sheet 3 to sheet n.

for example:  **`=SUM(INDIRECT("'"&F2&"'!C4"),INDIRECT("'"&F3&"'!C4")),`** the C4 does not change as I drag them across the board.

Any other idea?

Comment: An idea - if I understand correctly - is what if on your "Calc" sheet, row 1 lists all the sheet names in the workbook.  Then, under that, you can do a SUM() formula with indirect pointing to A1, B1, etc. to get the sheet name.  Then drag that across?

Comment: This is tagged VBA but you're aiming for a non-VBA solution?

Comment: That was my first idea.  However, the cells in the indirect function that refers to another sheet doesn't change as you drag.  Above, the C4 doesn't change.  So if I have 1000 cells, then I'd have to change for each one of them.

Comment: I would rather not, unless there are no solution without VBA.  Then that option is better than no option

Comment: @Seven - if you type that formula in, and drag, the "C4" does NOT change?  You're not using VBA to add that formula, or are you?

Comment: @user3578951 I am not using VBA.  Just cells formula

Comment: I think your answer is right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10378504/4717755) by @brettdj. I tried it on my workbook and it worked like a champ.

Comment: Can you just type the formula on sheet n, then copy/paste values?

Comment: @kyle they are imported files, and I have no access to them.

Comment: @Seven In that case I don't understand your question at all, sorry. You want to put data from sheet 3 on to sheet n right? How is that possible if you don't have access to either of those sheets?

Comment: are you able to add a start! sheet and an end! sheet to wrap around the editable data? that way your formula is really easy...

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess:

1. You have many sheets;
2. You can delete or add new sheet;
3. There are data in `Range("A1:Z1000")` in every sheet;
4. You want sum every sheet's `Range("A1:Z1000")` in sheet("Calc").Range("A1:Z1000");

Every sheet has data in `A1:Z1000`.
[image]

Sum in "Calc" sheet.
[image]

If so try this:

```
Sub SumEverySheet()

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim cellValue

For Each Sh In Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> "Sheet1" And Sh.Name <> "Calc" Then
        ' row: 1 to 1000
        For i = 1 To 1000
            ' A - Z (1 - 26)
            For j = 1 To 26
                cellValue = Sheets("Calc").Cells(i, j)
                sheetValue = Sh.Cells(i, j)
                Sheets("Calc").Cells(i, j) = sheetValue + cellValue
            Next j
        Next i
    End If
Next Sh
End Sub
```

Put this macro in `Workbook_AfterSave` can make it run automatically after save.

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    MsgBox "after save"
    Call SumEverySheet
End Sub
```

Hope this will help you.