# Excel 2016: Refer to last worksheet in a formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, named-ranges

So, I have this formula here (which works)

```
=SUM(SUMIF('Inventory 11.09.2018'!$B$2:$B$47;B2;'Inventory 11.09.2018'!$C$2:$C$47);SUMIF($H:$H;B2;$I:$I))
```

and I'd like to achieve, that instead of the actual worksheet name (Inventory 11.09.2018) the formula always refers to the last worksheet of the table. Every time an Inventory is done a worksheet is added to the table.

I did a bit of research and found this solution: [How do I get my formula to always reference to the last sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371030/how-do-i-get-my-formula-to-always-reference-to-the-last-sheet)

What I did with this solution is to define two range names.

wshNames

```
=RIGHT(GET.WORKBOOK(1),LEN(GET.WORKBOOK(1))-FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)))
```

wshNameLast

```
=INDEX(wshNames,COUNTA(wshNames)+RAND()*0)
```

I then proceeded to alter my formula into this:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(wshNameLast&"!$B$2:$B$47";B2;wshNameLast&"!$C$2:$C$47");SUMIF($H:$H;B2;$I:$I))
```

But it throws this error message when hitting return:
[Excel_error_in_formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPd7d.png)

Since this is German, it basically says:

> There's a problem with this formula.
>
> You didn't want to enter a formula?
>
> *And then explains what an apostrophe before a formula does.*

If I use the defined names solely in a formula like

```
=wshNameLast
```

they work. If I remove the "SUM" around the formula like this, just to test if it would work without "SUM"

```
SUMIF('Inventory 11.09.2018'!$B$2:$B$47;B2;'Inventory 11.09.2018'!$C$2:$C$47)
```

it also doesn't work. So I figure there's something wrong the defined range names in combination with the formula the way I wanna use it.

Question is: What am I doing wrong and how can I get to work? Also, I would like to solve this problem without VB/VBA if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the INDIRECT function to convert the string `wshNameLast&"!$B$2:$B$47"` to a range. Like this `INDIRECT(wshNameLast&"!$B$2:$B$47")`.

The complete formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(INDIRECT(wshNameLast&"!$B$2:$B$47");B2;INDIRECT(wshNameLast&"!$C$2:$C$47"));SUMIF($H:$H;B2;$I:$I))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marco!
With INDIRECT added into the formula at least it doesn't show an error message.
Unfortunately the result for this formula is #REF! (Or #REFERENCE? In German it says #BEZUG!)
Analyzing the calculation steps shows, that after Excel completely resolved `INDIRECT(wshNameLast&"!$B$2:$B$46")` this part turns into #REF!.

Any idea why?

Comment: This means that `wshNameLast&"!$B$2:$B$46"` is not a valid range reference. Does `=wshNameLast` return an existing sheetname? When i test the formula in my answer, it doesn't give an error.

Comment: `wshNameLast` returns an existing sheet name and it's always the last worksheet.

I noticed, that if i add a new and empty worksheet as last worksheet there's no error anymore.
I.e. I'm having the sheets "Stock", "Inventory 11.09.2018" and "Sheet1". Switching "Inventory" with "Sheet" results in an error again.

I just don't see what wrong with the worksheet "Inventory 11.09.2018". There's nothing special about it. Not even formulas are included!

I think I just gonna rebuild the whole thing step by step and see if it works.

Comment: Okay, that was a fast one.

Just plain copy and pasting the content of that Inventory worksheet into a new one solved it.

**BUT** renaming the new worksheet brings back the error. Turn out **a space in the worksheets name** causes the error!

Guess I'll simply work with an underscore then. Thanks a lot for the help, @Marco Vos.